# Some crazy equations

Tags: riddle, mathematics

```
8   = 2
68  = 3
91  = 1
32  = 0
883 = 4
761 = ?
```

What number should be instead of `?` in this: `76 = ?` according to other equations ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1 - It's the number of closed loops in the number.